# mangeto admin Current Configuration Scope

Tags: magento

I am facing this problem of Current Configuration Scope: in System => Configuration.
Single installation of Mangeto is used for multi store front end.
Users are single store front can access only their data using AITOC's Advanced permissions. 
When user is in configuration section, he has to uncheck the checkbox and then he can use the input to enter his data.
I want to remove this unchecking from every field so its easy for the user to but i cant locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could see if there's a pattern to the checkboxes in the DOM (html) and add a little bit of javascript to automatically clear them (or clear them and hide them).

We're upgrading to 1.7.0.0 and these checkboxes are all over the store config (not using AITOC extension, so I think the extension is unrelated). We've got to uncheck them to change any setting; beyond annoying.